# Keras based neural network not training

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, keras

I am training this very simple neural network using Keras library.

Irrsepctive of number of epochs, NN is not able to predict correctly even for a case covered in training set.

What am I doing wrong here.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras import optimizers
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
              loss='categorical_crossentropy',
              metrics=['accuracy'])


inputData=[[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]
outputData=[[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]

numpy_input=np.array(inputData).reshape(len(inputData),3)
numpy_output=np.array(outputData).reshape(len(inputData),3)

model.fit(numpy_input, numpy_output, nb_epoch=20, batch_size=3,verbose=1)

op=model.predict(np.array([0,0,1]).reshape(1,3))
print op
```

Output I am getting is [[ 0.41825652  0.32675183  0.25499159]] and many other variations.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Activation
from keras import optimizers
import numpy as np

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(3, input_dim=3))
model.add(Activation('sigmoid'))
model.add(Dense(3, activation='softmax'))

sgd = optimizers.SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)

model.compile(optimizer=sgd,
          loss='categorical_crossentropy',
          metrics=['accuracy'])


inputData=[[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]
outputData=[[0,0,1],[0,1,0],[1,0,0]]

numpy_input=np.array(inputData)
numpy_output=np.array(outputData)

model.fit(numpy_input, numpy_output, nb_epoch=50, batch_size=3,verbose=1)

op=model.predict(np.array([[0,0,1]]))
print(op)
```

That yields in my machine

```
[[ 0.30640799  0.34553316  0.34805891]]
```

Which is suggesting output as 0 0 1

Answer (score 0):

**Your main issue is you didn't run it for sufficient epochs (`nb_epoch=20` is too low):**

```
Epoch 20/20
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 1.1682 - acc: 0.3333
[[ 0.2559461   0.40617985  0.33787408]]
```

Clearly this isn't good enough, let's see if more epochs will help us converge. After some trial and error, it seems to needs around a minimum of 250 epochs to get the desired output:

```
Epoch 250/250
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.5997 - acc: 1.0000
[[ 0.06680837  0.27412242  0.65906924]]
```

It does seem to converge because after 500 or 2000 epochs it's even closer

```
Epoch 500/500
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.1502 - acc: 1.0000
[[ 0.06663816  0.04986271  0.88349915]]


Epoch 2000/2000
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0197 - acc: 1.0000
[[ 0.01536902  0.01592613  0.96870482]]
```

If it's unclear,  the only change I have made to your code is `nb_epoch=250`.
Note that values as low as 50 sometimes give accuracy 1.0, but it isn't stable across runs. For me 250 was stable.

**Trying ReLU instead of Sigmoid:**

@Marcin Możejko suggested we use a ReLU instead of the Sigmoid in your example, at 250 epoches I'm getting mixed results

```
Epoch 250/250
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.3139 - acc: 1.0000
[[ 0.22046153  0.14507896  0.6344595 ]]

Epoch 250/250
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.4994 - acc: 0.6667
[[ 0.04885471  0.47655082  0.47459444]]
```

and sometimes it converges really well towards 0 and 1

```
Epoch 250/250
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0189 - acc: 1.0000
[[ 0.00779702  0.00919682  0.98300618]]
```

With 500 epoches and ReLU I get stables results

```
Epoch 500/500
3/3 [==============================] - 0s - loss: 0.0263 - acc: 1.0000
[[ 0.0309988   0.03392733  0.93507391]]
```

So indeed ReLU seems to give slightly better results than a sigmoid with same epochs.

Comment: so turns out there is issue with initialization of keras random numbers.

Comment: so turns out there is issue with initialization of keras random numbers. I just added np.random.seed(7) and now I am getting all outputs correct. I tried many other seed values. Its still giving correct results for as less epochs as 20.